# Is there any angular test skeleton generators?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm searching some similar to PHPUnit Skeleton Generator just for Angular, maybe you could help me to find one ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into the [ng-boilerplate](http://joshdmiller.github.io/ng-boilerplate/#/home) project. It sets you up with a sane structure, including where to put tests and running them.

Comment: I got code which is well structured (by features) I already got some tests and I know how to run them. What I want is to generate basic test skeleton with all needed mocking dependencies, function calls and etc.

Comment: I doubt that such a library exists. It would basically automatically create everything needed for unit tests, and I've never heard of such a tool for any language. If you know of such a tool, please share it because I'd be very interested in how it works.

Comment: Lets take for example php https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/skeleton-generator.html


By the way I started working on my own test generator it is simple string parser and analyzer now works only with code that I have written, several small improvements and i might publish it as open source project ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which is a very nice scaffolding tool for JS projects.
It works around the concept of generators, different generators can generate different files for you. For example the angular-generator will help you with setting up an angular project and also add controllers, services and such.

Comment: will it help me to generate test skeletons ? cause I was searching for an example how do this with yeoman, but I couldn't find one.

well I found this http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html
I will continue investigation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well you could use the jasmine generator https://github.com/yeoman/generator-jasmine. But I don't know how smart it is, such as if it will parse a controller and create test stubs for you or not.